# Group by defined conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below. All the values are populated when Type=Forecast.
When Type=Sales, All Regions are NULL.

Looking back at the Forecast, each ID can only be mapped to a single Region. However in some cases there can be 2 Region mapped to one ID. If this occurs then I would like to focus only on the first region.

Also note there can be ID present in Type=Forecast and not present in Type=Sales or vice versa.

```
TABLE 1
ID    Region   Type
123xy   ASPAC    Forecast
123xy   ASPAC    Forecast
456za   ASPAC    Forecast
456za   EMEA     Forecast
789sw   LATAM    Forecast
789sw   EMEA     Forecast
999ww   NORTH    Forecast
123xy            Sales
123xy            Sales
456za            Sales
789sw            Sales
111xx            Sales
```

My expected output would be  :

```
TABLE 2: Expected Output
ID    Region   Type
123xy   ASPAC    Forecast
123xy   ASPAC    Forecast
456za   ASPAC    Forecast
456za   EMEA     Forecast
789sw   LATAM    Forecast
789sw   EMEA     Forecast
999ww   NORTH    Forecast
123xy   ASPAC    Sales
123xy   ASPAC    Sales
456za   ASPAC    Sales
789sw   LATAM    Sales
789sw   LATAM    Sales
111xx            Sales
```

The expected output would ideally ALTER/UPDATE the table with the new populated values for Region in Sales.
However I am not sure how to proceed with this in the most efficient manner possible ? I was thinking inserting all data with Type = Forecast into another table, grouping them by ID and Region, removing any duplicates and then doing a LEFT JOIN TABLE 1 vs TEMP table.

Answer (score 0):

Get the minimum value for the ID's join it with the the table again and use the minimum value row for those that do not have Region defined.

```
select t1.ID, ifnull(t1.Region, t.Region), t1.Type
from table1 t1
  join (
    select t2.Region, min(ID) as ID
    from table1 t2
    group by t2.Region
  ) t on t.ID=t1.ID
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e245e9/1)

Comment: The ID can have text as well in between them so in this case it is not possible to get the Minimum. I have updated my question to reflect this

Comment: You can get minimum from a char-column. The SQLFiddle is updated. If the minimum is not the definition you want for "first region", then you would need to have some other definition for the "first region". Without any ordering column(s) there is no "first". The database table is a set of rows.